# Plot bar graph with 3 variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Im sure this is fairly easy but im new to R. how do you plot a bar graph with the following data.

```
D_data <- data.frame(month=c(1,2,3,4),
                 A=c(22,55,66,88),
                 B=c(7,8,5,8),
                 c=c(1,2,9,10))
```

The bar graph as x axis as the month, y as the value of each category A, B, C. There should be 3 bars for each month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged this with `ggplot2`, I assume you don't want a base R solution, but you can use `pivot_longer()` to tidy your data and then use `ggplot()` with another argument.

More importantly, you don't have enough values to make boxplots with `month` and letters. However, you can make a bar plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
D_data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -month) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

```
D_data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -month) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = month, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           position = "dodge",
           aes(fill = name))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes thank you so much!! Clean and simple.

Comment: I have come to another road block where the months has associated years, years=c(2021,2021,2022,2022).  How do you  incorporate facet_wrap= ~years to the bar graph so it shows that first 2 months is 2021 and last 2 months is 2022.

Comment: If you have a different question, you should make another post and provide your new data in that post. Also, if I've answered your question, please check the green checkmark next to this answer to mark your question as answered.